# Error with JMS Appender in Log4j2 going to Wildfly 14

Tags: java, osgi, wildfly, log4j2

Using Log4j2 2.11.1 with Wildfly 14.0.1, OpenJDK 11.  We have a custom OSGi client application that logs both to a console appender and to a JMS appender to send logging events to the Wildfly server.

Prior to Log4j2, we were programmatically sticking a JMS appender into our Log4j configuration, which worked fine.  This really wasn't necessary so with our recent upgrade to Log4j2, I'm trying to using a log4j2.xml configuration to handle all of that and simplify our code.

We have a client class that this successfully connecting to our Wildfly JMS and receiving messages, using the following:

```
  topicConnFacName: com.rsc.mmpl.TopicConnectionFactory
  initialContextFacName: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
  URL: http-remoting://JDEVDWS166:9090
  Topic name: com.rsc.mmpl.MsgHndlrTopic
```

My log4j2.xml configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%p %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{3}[line %L] - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="com.rsc.mmpl.MsgHndlrTopic"
         factoryName="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"
         factoryBindingName="com.rsc.mmpl.TopicConnectionFactory"
         ignoreExceptions="false"
         providerURL="http-remoting://JDEVDWS166:9090">
         <JsonLayout properties="true" complete="true"/>
    </JMS>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If I comment out my JMS Appender, it works fine, so I know that my log4j is setup correctly from a classpath perspective (log4j core and api jars, as well as jackson jars, and jboss-client.jar are all on the overall classpath).

However, when running my client app with the JMS Appender, I get the following error:

```
[stderr] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.remoting3.ConfigurationEndpointSupplier$Holder
[stderr]    at org.jboss.remoting3.ConfigurationEndpointSupplier.get(ConfigurationEndpointSupplier.java:84)
[stderr]    at org.jboss.remoting3.ConfigurationEndpointSupplier.get(ConfigurationEndpointSupplier.java:40)
[stderr]    at org.wildfly.common.context.ContextManager.getPrivileged(ContextManager.java:286)
[stderr]    at org.jboss.remoting3.Endpoint.getCurrent(Endpoint.java:81)
[stderr]    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProviderFactory.getEndpoint(RemoteNamingProviderFactory.java:49)
[stderr]    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProviderFactory.supportsUriScheme(RemoteNamingProviderFactory.java:40)
[stderr]    at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.getProviderContext(WildFlyRootContext.java:784)
[stderr]    at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:140)
[stderr]    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.JndiManager.lookup(JndiManager.java:172)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager.createConnection(JmsManager.java:323)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager.<init>(JmsManager.java:250)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager.<init>(JmsManager.java:54)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager$JmsManagerFactory.createManager(JmsManager.java:130)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsManager$JmsManagerFactory.createManager(JmsManager.java:125)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsAppender$Builder.build(JmsAppender.java:118)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.JmsAppender$Builder.build(JmsAppender.java:50)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:243)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
[stderr]    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:648)
[stderr]    at com.rsc.delphi.logger.log4j.Log4jLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
[stderr]    ... 20 more
```

Looking at the Holder source, it appears something is going wrong with the static block there but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Is there any way to get more information to figure out what is failing here?  Again, programmatically connecting to my Wildfly JMS is fine, just seems to be an issue with Log4j2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace by chance? Also instead of `http-remote` you should use `remote+http`. Both should work, but `remote+http` is the preferred protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, my first guess is that the issue doesn't lie in the top of the stack trace there. That class loading issue is likely originating from where `log4j2` is getting the connection to the `WildFly` naming interface.

It looks like a new [`InitialContextFactory` (subclassed) module is now provided](http://docs.wildfly.org/14/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#Application_Client_Migration). That means you'll have to change:

```
org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
```

To:

```
org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory
```

Not having looked too deeply into it, it looks like the [new `ICF`](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-naming-client/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wildfly/naming/client/WildFlyRootContext.java) has a little more fancy logic for handling `ClassLoader` issues than the [old `ICF`](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/14.0.1.Final/naming/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/naming/InitialContext.java)...

Comment: Definitely a classloader issue.  I created a small test class and it works just fine, so it appears it has something to do with the OSGi stuff. I thought putting the jars on the "top level" classpath (which I thought all bundle classloaders would have access to) would do the trick but apparently that's not cutting it.  I might need to deploy the jboss and log4j jars are bundles?   I changed the factory as you suggested and a got a much more verbose set of errors, so that's good, still reading through it.  Thanks for the suggestion!